# Bug with single digit numbers in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use single digit numbers in calculations in my calculator App, calcNumber2 is still the same as calcNumber. In more digits calcNumber2 changes as declared.
For example:
99 - 33 will be 66, but 9 - 3 will be 0, because calcNumber2 wont update.

app github: https://github.com/Pochmannn/calculus

```
class _CalculusState extends State<Calculus> {
  String screenNumber = '0';
  String screenNumber2 = '';
  double calcNumber = 0;
  double calcNumber2 = 0;
  String option = '';

  clickNumber(String textTile) {
    if (screenNumber == '0') {
      setState(() => screenNumber = textTile);
    } else {
      setState(
        () => screenNumber += textTile,
      );
      setState(() => calcNumber = double.parse(screenNumber));
    }
  }

  void resetNumber() {
    setState(() => screenNumber = '0');
    setState(() => screenNumber2 = '');
    setState(() => calcNumber = 0);
    setState(() => calcNumber2 = 0);
  }

  getResult(option) {
    setState(() => screenNumber = calcNumber.toString());
    switch (option) {
      case '/':
        {
          setState(() => calcNumber = calcNumber2 / calcNumber);
          setState(() => screenNumber = calcNumber.toString());
        }
        break;

      case '+':
        {
          setState(() => calcNumber = calcNumber2 + calcNumber);
          setState(() => screenNumber = calcNumber.toString());
        }
        break;

      case '-':
        {
          setState(() => calcNumber = calcNumber2 - calcNumber);
          setState(() => screenNumber = calcNumber.toString());
        }
        break;
    }
    setState(() => screenNumber2 = '');
  }

  getCurrentOption(option) {
    setState(() => calcNumber2 = calcNumber);
    setState(() => screenNumber2 = screenNumber);
    setState(() => screenNumber = '0');
  }
```

I tried making result in separate variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing `setState(() => calcNumber = double.parse(screenNumber));` inside your first if statement, but you'll need to think of changing it entirely, to avoid number duplication on initial number addition.

Comment: thx, works now.